# Select statement as column value with place holders

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a scenerio where my select statment is stored as a column value with below structure in a table.

```
 Id               Query
 ----             -----
 1                SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMP_ID= In_EMP_ID
```

I have a procedure in which empid is passed as parameter, cursor in procedure fetches above select statement from table EMP based on Id which is 1 here.

Procedure is

```
  Create or replace procedure EMP (In_EMP_ID IN NUMBER)
  AS
  CURSOR get_stmt(id IN VARCHAR2) IS 
  SELECT Query from EMP WHERE id = id;

  l_select_stmt varchar2(200);
  BEGIN

  OPEN get_stmt(1);
  Fetch get_stmt into l_select_stmt;

  END;
```

Now, Is there any possibility where In_EMP_ID could be assigned to EMP_ID in where clause of my fetched select statement which is now available in l_select_stmt ?

Comment: Try to store till EMP_ID= and in your procedure use string operation to frame your query.

Comment: Thanks, thought for this solution however I have more values to put in my where condition so i have to split my query 4 times which i am not looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to execute that select statement using `EXECUMTE IMMEDIATE`, you can use a bind variable to pass the ID. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_queries (
  id NUMBER,
  my_query VARCHAR2(200)
);

INSERT INTO my_queries VALUES (1, 'SELECT fname FROM EMP WHERE EMPID = :In_EMP_ID');
COMMIT;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE emp_proc(In_EMP_ID IN NUMBER)
AS
  CURSOR get_stmt(id_par IN VARCHAR2) IS 
    SELECT my_query FROM my_queries WHERE id = id_par;

  l_select_stmt varchar2(200);
  l_name VARCHAR2(40);
BEGIN
  OPEN get_stmt(1);
  FETCH get_stmt INTO l_select_stmt;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_select_stmt 
    INTO l_name
    USING IN in_emp_id;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_name);
END;
/

EXEC emp_proc(1);
```

Notice that, in the query, you now have `:in_emp_id` instead of just `in_emp_id`. Also notice that I have changed some of the names of columns/tables for this particular example just to show how to use the `USING` clause of the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Output:

```
John
```

Comment: Thanks very much, which if i have more values to check in where clause ? can i use multiple values in USING clause?

Comment: @user1717270 Yes, you can use more than one, just specify them after commas like: `USING variable1, variable2, variable3` and so on. Each variable will be bound to a placeholder defined in your query with `:` (colon).

Comment: got it..we can use multiple columns in USING IN clause.. Thanks